# How to redirect incompatible clients to mobile version of Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011?

Tags: iis, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I want simplify access to Dynamics CRM 2011 by redirecting users to mobile version if they open CRM link in browser that is not a compatible client. Looks like there is no out of the box solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to [write an HTTP Module](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227673.aspx) that would do this.  It obviously isn't a "supported" customization but should be easy to remove if it causes problems.

The other option is to wait for [the Q4 update that is supposed to add multi-browser support](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2011/05/12/statement-of-direction-for-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011.aspx).